# Using the new MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth namespace

Tags: ios5, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I have found a few samples on how to use *GameKit* for bluetooth communication and even accessing bluetooth functionality using native code but no example on how to use the *MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth* namespace.
Seems a shame using hacks when the full implementation is just waiting to be used.
Can anyone please share a sample or source (a link to a book would work as well) for the new *MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreBluetooth is just for communicating with devices that utilise the Bluetooth Low Energy Profile, such as watches, heart rate monitors etc.. It is not possible to use any other profiles with CoreBluetooth, so not possible to connect to another phone, a computer etc... 
(Although given the name, I hope in future apple will provide lower level access to bluetooth comms in this framework)